# Foreach loop stops at first occurrence

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a `for each` loop, where I check if the reservation is reserved on the specific ski and if `DateTime.Now` is within the date of the reservation. If yes, the `IsReserved` property is set to `true`.

This is working perfectly, so I can reserve an item. Now I am figuring out how to deal with the situation if the reservation is deleted. I want to set  the `IsReserved` property to `false` on specific item if the reservation on it was deleted.

**Here is the loop**

```
foreach (Ski s in skies)
{

    foreach (Reservation r in reservations) 
    {
        var datumdo1 = r.DateTo;
        var datumdo2 = datumdo1.ToShortDateString();
        var datumted1 = DateTime.Now;
        var datumted2 = datumted1.ToShortDateString();
        var datumod1 = r.DateFrom;
        var datumod2 = datumod1.ToShortDateString();

        if ((s.Id == r.Reserved.Id && (r.DateFrom < DateTime.Now || datumod2 == datumted2)) && (r.DateTo > DateTime.Now || datumdo2 == datumted2) && (r.Reserved.IsReserved == false)) 
        {
            s.IsReserved = true;
        }

    skiDao.update(s);

    }

    if(reservations.Count == 0)
    {
        s.IsReserved = false;
    }

}
```

I have tried adding this under the first condition:

```
if(s.Id != r.Reserved.Id)
{
s.IsReserved = false;
}
```

However, the iteration stops at the first occurrence. So it only checks one reservation. How to make it go through all the reservations and sets `s.IsReserved = false` only if there is none with the same ID as the item ID?

Comment: may be `skies` only contains one value, or is there any error?

Comment: Currently there are two items in skies and on both the reservation is made. If i delete one, both items still have IsReserved set to true. Only if I delete all the reservations, all ski sets IsReserved to false. @IrshadJm

Comment: from which line did the itration stops?

Comment: I think I explained it wrong. The only thing I need to figure out now is how to set IsReserved to false on a ski when its reservation has been deleted. Right now it only sets to false when there are none reservations. @IrshadJm

Comment: if(reservations.Count == 0 || !s.IsReserved) helps?

Comment: You need to learn to use your IDE's debugger to step through the code and inspect the values as you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going with your original idea here. I think where your proposal goes off is it would reset s.IsReserved on the first mismatching ID (which could just mean it was not the first you looked at) as opposed if they all don't match (reservation was deleted). Here is how you might do it.

```
foreach (Ski s in skies)
{
    var skiFound = false;    
foreach (Reservation r in reservations) 
{
    skiFound = skiFound || (s.Id == r.Reserved.Id);
    var datumdo1 = r.DateTo;
    var datumdo2 = datumdo1.ToShortDateString();
    var datumted1 = DateTime.Now;
    var datumted2 = datumted1.ToShortDateString();
    var datumod1 = r.DateFrom;
    var datumod2 = datumod1.ToShortDateString();

    if ((s.Id == r.Reserved.Id && (r.DateFrom < DateTime.Now || datumod2 == datumted2)) && (r.DateTo > DateTime.Now || datumdo2 == datumted2) && (r.Reserved.IsReserved == false)) 
    {
        s.IsReserved = true;
    }

skiDao.update(s);

}
if (!skiFound)
{
    s.IsReserved = false;
}

//now probably no longer needed
    if(reservations.Count == 0)
    {
        s.IsReserved = false;
    }

//commenters may well be right that for this change to stick, you need to update the database

}
```

Comment: Finally! I have been searching for the solution a couple of hours. Great and working solution Jeremy!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
foreach (Ski s in skies)
{
     var reser = reservations.where(a=>a.ReservedId == s.Id).firstordefault(); 
     if(reser != null) // cheks if no reservation available
     {
        s.IsReserved = false;
     }
     else{
          // if you need
     }
}
```

Comment: JFI, with your approach the line ``skiDao.update(s);`` wont be called for each Iteration of **reservations**.

Comment: Updated my answer, i think it will do now

Comment: Now you are calling ``skiDao.update(s);`` on each iteration of **skies** and not **reservations**.

Comment: he needs to update `skies` if there is no reservation available with one `ski`

Answer (score -2):

Instead of doing a foreach on the reservations, you could just use LINQ

```
s.IsReserved = reservations.Any(r => (s.Id == r.Reserved.Id && (r.DateFrom < DateTime.Now || datumod2 == datumted2)) && (r.DateTo > DateTime.Now || datumdo2 == datumted2) && (r.Reserved.IsReserved == false));
```

This would replace the whole loop and the last conditional.

Comment: But, does that answer his question?

Comment: How to make it go through all the reservations and sets s.IsReserved = false only if there is none with the same ID as the item ID? <= That is the question, and it does exactly that, I guess yes.

Comment: JFI, with your approach the line ``skiDao.update(s);`` wont be called for each Iteration of **reservations**.

Comment: True, still, seems like something that can be done outside of the reservations loop.

Comment: Probably, seemed strange in the first place.